# Setting URLSearch Params in next.js 14

Tags: next.js, next.js13, app-router, urlsearchparams

I want to set query parameters when filters updates, I am able to add it correctly with router.push, but I am getting problem to reset it. I don't know how I can do it. Please check below router.push('')
[image]

Comment: what exactly do you mean by resetting it?